# How do I build a Policy POJO with Statements with Resources in AWS SDK for Java v2.x?

Tags: aws-sdk-java-2.0

All the v2 documentation around the subject just assumes an already serialized json string, but in our existing code using the v1 SDK we easily create Policy objects with Statement objects with Resource objects

```kotlin
import com.amazonaws.auth.policy.Policy
import com.amazonaws.auth.policy.Resource
import com.amazonaws.auth.policy.Statement

    fun createGetPolicy(
        getResourceStrings: Collection<String>,
    ): Policy = Policy()
        .withStatements(
            Statement(Statement.Effect.Allow)
                .withActions(S3Actions.GetObject)
                .withResources(
                    *getResourceStrings.map(::Resource).toTypedArray()
                )
        )
```

The `software.amazon.awssdk.services.iam.model.Policy.Builder` in v2 doesn't resemble this at all, which makes me think there is some other way to do this?